# Error with extends Fragment

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

I trying working it but I don't can. I want do Login for facebook but I don't now. Any example?

```
public class login extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,     Bundle saveStanceState){

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_login, container, false);

    loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");
    loginButton.setFragment(this);


    // Callback registration
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

    });
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_login, container, false);
}
```

Comment: what is the error ? post log cat

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.xxx.login cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

Comment: extend  Activity not Fragment

Comment: if extend is Activity I have the error: "in FacebookButtonBase cannot be applied"

Answer (score 0):

Your `return` is purposed to the new inflated `View`, your code should look like this:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_login, container, false);
...
return view;
```